# Save average review score or calculate at every request?

Tags: relational-database

I have a city review app and will let people review the cities where they have been. Forget about users for a while.

So in the db will look like this

```
CITIES:             REVIEWS:

| id | name     |   | id | CityId | score | 
|----|----------|   |----|--------|-------|
| 1  | Tokyo    |   | 1  | 1      | 3     |
| 2  | New York |   | 2  | 1      | 1     |
| 3  | Paris    |   | 3  | 3      | 5     |
                    | 4  | 3      | 2     |
                    | 5  | 3      | 1     |
```

**My numbers:**
I may have 1000 different cities and 10-50 reviews for each city (but reviews count will continue to grow)

**Options:**
A: Add a column `averageReview` to the `CITIES` table and update that average on every new review and simply pickup that value every time I have to retrieve a city

B: Calculate the average every time I have to retrieve a city

Which is the most common way to get the average review every time I need to retrieve a city?

Comment: A except you only update it once a day

Comment: Your numbers are small enough that you could calculate the average with every request.  However, the timeliness of the average is not as important as the overall processing speed, so I agree with @Ewan.

Comment: @Ewan: IMO, that's premature optimisation. Keep it simple for now, if later on calculating the review score becomes a major bottleneck, then think about caching/batching them.

Comment: @LieRyan the more experience you get, the less premature optimisation seems.

Answer (score 2):

In this case: Add a column “number of reviews” and a column “sum of reviews”. Then when a review is added, it’s a trivial change to the cities database that doesn’t require reading all the reviews for the city. Just add 1 to the count and the score to the sum of scores. And calculating the average is a single division.

Comment: Im with you, but to not modifi a table that could be "readonly" I would create a new table  with 3 rows: CityId, ReviewsNumber and ReviewsSum (As example)

Comment: @Balbu  I think it is safe to assume they can change the table unless mentioned otherwise. The OP actually specified changing the CITIES table themselves.

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use a **database trigger** to calculate the average review score when a new review is added by a user, and store that calculated value in a column in your cities table.  This way the score only needs to be calculated when the reviews for a city change, and will always be up to date, and its handled directly by the database rather than your code.

An alternative to the above is a stored procedure that your code calls which does the insert and calculation, rather than relying on the trigger.

Each DBMS is a bit different in how that is done exactly, but every major database server would support them.